# html element query selector is null when popup is launched second time

Tags: javascript

I've created a method for displaying a validation summary. I have a partial control with a table structure in it. I populate and create the table dynamically using javascript. The popup displays fine on the first click, and then i close the popup. But on the second click, it fails, the element selector returns null. Why is that?

```
const titleText = document.querySelector("#titleTxt");
```

Here is the partial control:

```
<div id="validationSummary" style="visibility: hidden">
<div id="entityList" style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold">
    <span id="titleTxt"></span>
    <table class="table" style="border:solid 1px black;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" style="text-align:center; border:solid 1px black;">#</th>
                <th scope="col" style="text-align:center; border:solid 1px black;">Validation</th>
                <th scope="col" style="text-align:center; border:solid 1px black;">Details</th>
                <th scope="col" style="text-align:center; border:solid 1px black;">Severity</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tableBody">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the method  to display the popup:

```
function DisplayValidationSummary() {
    let accountNumber = '@Model.AccountNumber';
    let versionId = '@Model.VersionId';
    let rollYr = $('#accountRollYear').val();
    let validationURL = asrAppApiHelper.getValidationErrorsUrl(accountNumber, versionId, rollYr);
    $.when(asrKendoHelper.asrDataSet.getDataFromUrlByPromise(validationURL)).then((validationResult) => {
        if (validationResult.length > 0) {
            const tableData = validationResult.map(function (value, index) {
                let iconCol = `<td></td>`
                if (value.validationSeverity === 'Error') {
                    iconCol = `<td <i class="fa fa-times" style="color:red"></i></td>`
                }
                if (value.validationSeverity === 'Warning') {
                    iconCol = `<td <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" style="color:orange"></i></td>`
                }
                if (value.validationSeverity === 'Ok') {
                    iconCol = `<td <i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green"></i></td>`
                }
                return (
                    `<tr>
                        <td style="border-right:solid 1px black;">${index + 1}</td>
                        <td style="border-right:solid 1px black;">${value.validationType}</td>
                        <td style="border-right:solid 1px black;">${value.validationDetail}</td>
                        ${iconCol}
                    </tr>`
                );
            }).join('');
            const titleText = document.querySelector("#titleTxt");
            titleText.innerHTML = "A/C:&nbsp;" + accountNumber + "&emsp;Version #" + versionId + "&emsp;Validation Summary";
            const tableBody = document.querySelector("#tableBody");
            tableBody.innerHTML = tableData;
            const validationSummary = document.querySelector("#validationSummary");
            validationSummary.style.visibility  = "visible";
            getAlertWindow(validationSummary);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you by any chance remove the element from the DOM when closing the popup?

Comment: So where do you remove the pop up?

Comment: I am not destroying the popup, but it looks like the kendo popup might be doing something and destroying it. If i refresh the page, and click on the popup it loads fine the first time.
I used the console to check if the validation summary exists and it says it doesn't exist after the first click.

Comment: Sounds like your pop up code removes the element so you need to probably clone it. It is a guess since we have no clue how you make the pop up. That is all hidden from us.

Comment: @epascarello I will check and get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed everything with some help to look like this:

```
$("#button-open-validations").click((e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        DisplayValidationSummary();
    });


function displayValidationSummaryPromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let accountNumber = '@Model.AccountNumber';
            let versionId = '@Model.VersionId';
            let rollYr = $('#accountRollYear').val();

        let isvalidationFailed = false;
        let validationURL = asrAppApiHelper.getValidationErrorsUrl(accountNumber, versionId, rollYr);
        $.when(asrKendoHelper.asrDataSet.getDataFromUrlByPromise(validationURL)).then((validationResult) => {
            if (validationResult.length > 0) {
                const tableData = validationResult.map(function (value, index) {
                    let iconRow = `<td></td>`
                    if (value.validationSeverity === 'Error') {
                        if (isvalidationFailed != true)
                            isvalidationFailed = true;
                        iconRow = `<td <i class="fa fa-times" style="color:red"></i></td>`
                    }
                    if (value.validationSeverity === 'Warning') {
                        iconRow = `<td <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" style="color:orange"></i></td>`
                    }
                    if (value.validationSeverity === 'Ok') {
                        iconRow = `<td <i class="fa fa-check" style="color:green"></i></td>`
                    }
                    return (
                        `<tr>
                        <td style="border-right:solid 1px black;">${index + 1}</td>
                        <td style="border-right:solid 1px black;">${value.validationType}</td>
                        <td style="border-right:solid 1px black;">${value.validationDetail}</td>
                        ${iconRow}
                    </tr>`
                    );
                }).join('');
                let valid =
                    `<div id="validationSummary" >
                                <div id="entityList" style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold">
                                    <span id="titleTxt">A/C:&nbsp;${accountNumber}&emsp;Version # ${versionId} &emsp;Validation Summary</span>
                                    <table class="table" style="border:solid 1px black;">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th scope="col" style="text-align:center; border:solid 1px black;">#</th>
                                                <th scope="col" style="text-align:center; border:solid 1px black;">Validation</th>
                                                <th scope="col" style="text-align:center; border:solid 1px black;">Details</th>
                                                <th scope="col" style="text-align:center; border:solid 1px black;">Severity</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody id="tableBody">${tableData}</tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                    </div>`
                resolve({ summary:valid, errorFlag: isvalidationFailed});
            }
        });
    });
}

function DisplayValidationSummary() {

    displayValidationSummaryPromise().then((validationSummary) => {
        getAlertWindow(validationSummary.summary);
    });

}
```

Deleted the partial control and am now creating the whole table in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As the other commenters noted, you must be removing the element from the DOM perhaps with a call to .remove()?  You can instead set its visibility back to hidden:

```js
validationSummary.style.visibility  = "hidden";
```

Comment: If i make this the last line in my javascript code, the popup content is blank because the element is now hidden again.

Comment: You will want two different functions.  One to make visibility visible and the other to make it hidden.  Use javascript events like onClick to call your functions.